# Adding exception handling and improving the below stored procedure and job in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have written database scheduler job in oracle database which is currently configured to run after every 12 hours. This job call a stored procedure which does the delta table clean up task only if mv refresh  is complete and mv last refresh time is greater than last run time of clean up job.

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
    job_name        => 'TABLE_CLEAN_UP_JOB',
    job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
    job_action      => 'TABLE_CLEAN_UP',
    start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    repeat_interval => 'freq=hourly;interval=12',
    enabled         => TRUE);
END;
/
```

below is the stored  procedure

```
create or replace procedure TABLE_CLEAN_UP
is
refresh_date timestamp(6);
v_exists NUMBER;
outcome VARCHAR2(100);
cnt NUMBER;
i NUMBER := 0;
begin

SELECT count(1) into cnt FROM all_mviews WHERE owner = 'M_TO' AND mview_name = 'DC_CASHFLOW_VIEW' or  mview_name = 'DC_CASHFLOW_VIEW_ZERO' and LAST_REFRESH_TYPE='COMPLETE';

   if cnt=2 then
     FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM all_mviews WHERE owner = 'P_SM_TO' AND mview_name = 'DC_CASHFLOW_VIEW' or  mview_name = 'DC_CASHFLOW_VIEW_ZERO' and LAST_REFRESH_TYPE='COMPLETE')
     LOOP
            Select LAST_START_DATE into refresh_date from USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS 

where JOB_NAME='TABLE_CLEAN_UP_JOB';
          if (CAST(rec.LAST_REFRESH_DATE AS TIMESTAMP) > refresh_date) then
                  i := i + 1;  
      end if; 
     END LOOP;

     if i=2 then
            delete DC_CASHFLOW_DELTA;
     end if; 
   end if;

end;
/
```

now there are two concerns with respect to this

first I haven't done the proper exception handling so please advise 
how to proper exception handling in above stored procedure

also please advise how can incorporate the logic in a loop.. if the clean-up doesn’t happen, it should sleep for 15 mins and then re-attempt.

Please advise folks how the improvements could be done
any suggestions would be appreciated

Folks can somebody pls advise on this

Comment: Why do you believe that exception handling is needed?  What exceptions do you want to catch and why?  `dbms_sceduler` will already do a fair amount of logging if your code throws an unhandled exception.  Are there exceptions you expect to see that you can realistically handle?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this looks like a Code Review question

Comment: i am posting it for code review please

Comment: Then you want to post on codereview.stackexchange not stackoverflow

Comment: @Cavin done pls , the thing in which i was interested how can i throw exceptions lets say if if cnt=2 is not met then i should throw the exception at that stage and second thing is that instead of creating a job is there any other best way to schedule.

Comment: I see this was rejected at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142326/adding-exception-handling-and-improving-the-below-stored-procedure-and-job-in-or as incomplete and/or broken code. You're having no luck with this question. From a code review perspective, it needs formatting as it is beyond unformatted - I'd call it antiformatted. Also, `count(*)` is the standard row count expression, not `count(some meaningless literal)`.

Comment: @William Thanks but can you please advise the queries to the answer which I have asked hope you will able to understand much

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cleaned-up version (untested of course). I took out the loop as it seemed to boil down to two counts, and I changed the `or` constructions in your `where` clauses to `in ()` as it's simpler and you were missing some brackets so it would have given incorrect results.

I'm never keen on hardcoding schema names - perhaps they should be passed as parameters or fetched from a config table?

The exception handling looks fine as it is. (It will fail with a `no_data_found` if there is no `'TABLE_CLEAN_UP_JOB'`, but I'd say it should fail in that situation because part of the system is missing. Maybe an exception handler for that specific case could provide a better message using `raise_application_error`, or just log a message and continue, if that's what you want it to do. It's up to you.)

```
create or replace procedure table_clean_up
is
    v_refresh_date   date;
    v_table_count_m  integer;
    v_table_count_p  integer;

begin
    select count(*) into v_table_count_m
    from   all_mviews
    where  owner = 'M_TO'
    and    mview_name in ('DC_CASHFLOW_VIEW','DC_CASHFLOW_VIEW_ZERO')
    and    last_refresh_type = 'COMPLETE';

    if v_table_count_m = 2 then
        select cast(last_start_date as date) into v_refresh_date
        from   user_scheduler_jobs
        where  job_name = 'TABLE_CLEAN_UP_JOB';

        select count(*) into v_table_count_p
        from   all_mviews m
        where  m.owner = 'P_SM_TO'
        and    m.mview_name in ('DC_CASHFLOW_VIEW', 'DC_CASHFLOW_VIEW_ZERO')
        and    m.last_refresh_type = 'COMPLETE'
        and    m.last_refresh_date > v_refresh_date;

        if v_table_count_p = 2 then
            delete dc_cashflow_delta;
        end if;
    end if;

end;
```

I didn't quite understand the scheduling question. You have a job `'TABLE_CLEAN_UP_JOB'` that calls the above procedure every 12 hours, and inside the procedure you check for some MV refreshes since the last job run (12 hours ago), but if there weren't any, then you want to reschedule it to retry in 15 minutes. I am probably missing something, but why not just schedule it to run every 15 minutes in the first place?

Anyway if you really wanted one procedure call to sit there retrying for up to 12 hours, you might try something along the lines of the following:

```
create or replace procedure table_clean_up
is
    v_refresh_date   date;
    v_table_count_m  integer;
    v_table_count_p  integer;
    v_loopcount      integer := 48;
begin
    while v_loopcount > 0 loop
        select count(*) into v_table_count_m
        from   all_mviews
        where  owner = 'M_TO'
        and    mview_name in ('DC_CASHFLOW_VIEW','DC_CASHFLOW_VIEW_ZERO')
        and    last_refresh_type = 'COMPLETE';

        if v_table_count_m = 2 then
            select cast(last_start_date as date) into v_refresh_date
            from   user_scheduler_jobs
            where  job_name = 'TABLE_CLEAN_UP_JOB';

            select count(*) into v_table_count_p
            from   all_mviews m
            where  m.owner = 'P_SM_TO'
            and    m.mview_name in ('DC_CASHFLOW_VIEW', 'DC_CASHFLOW_VIEW_ZERO')
            and    m.last_refresh_type = 'COMPLETE'
            and    m.last_refresh_date > v_refresh_date;

            if v_table_count_p = 2 then
                delete dc_cashflow_delta;
                exit;
            end if;
        end if;

        dbms_lock.sleep(60 * 15);
        v_loopcount := v_loopcount -1;
    end loop;
end;
```

(The magic numbers for how long to sleep and how many iterations to attempt should probably be passed in as parameters or configured in a table.)

Comment: Thanks a lot ,amazing piece of help now i can grasp more , yeah i have notice and will try to customise the code one more help neede fro you please lets say  we need to put the logic in a loop such that  if the clean-up doesn not happen, it should sleep for 15 mins and then re-attempt , please advise how can i incorporate this into above piece of logic

Comment: I'm still not quite sure why you couldn't just schedule it more frequently and let dbms_scheduler handle the looping, but I've added an example anyway.

Comment: Thanks William once again Thanks a lot,  request you to please advise how can we schedule it Through DB scheduler do we need to create the schedule as I have create d the job which call the stored procedures,  Please advise

Comment: Can't you just change your existing job definition from every 12 hours to every 15 minutes?

Comment: Sure William I will set to intervals to 15 I'm job definition Thanks in advance,  request you to o are show how can we create a scheduler I mean how can we please write a scheduler

Comment: I will set the property in job by minute =15

Comment: please advise that rite now we check for some MV refreshes since the last job run (12 hours ago), but if there weren't any, then I simply want to reschedule it to retry in 15 minutes so how can I add this condition inn loop let's say if mv are not referred then simply log the message rest if it is refresh then continue  to do the things as present, please advise