# how to put stored procedure job for sleep for duration of 35 mins

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have below piece of code that is below is stored procedure to clean up the table based on certain conditions that is there is view and if it get refreshed , now please advise if  we need to put the logic in a loop.. if the clean-up doesn’t happen, it should sleep for 15 mins and then re-attempt , please advise how to achieve this

```
create or replace procedure table_clean_up
is
    v_refresh_date   date;
    v_table_count_m  integer;
    v_table_count_p  integer;

begin
    select count(*) into v_table_count_m
    from   all_mviews
    where  owner = 'M_TO'
    and    mview_name in ('DC_CASHFLOW_VIEW','DC_CASHFLOW_VIEW_ZERO')
    and    last_refresh_type = 'COMPLETE';

    if v_table_count_m = 2 then
        select cast(last_start_date as date) into v_refresh_date
        from   user_scheduler_jobs
        where  job_name = 'TABLE_CLEAN_UP_JOB';

        select count(*) into v_table_count_p
        from   all_mviews m
        where  m.owner = 'P_SM_TO'
        and    m.mview_name in ('DC_CASHFLOW_VIEW', 'DC_CASHFLOW_VIEW_ZERO')
        and    m.last_refresh_type = 'COMPLETE'
        and    m.last_refresh_date > v_refresh_date;

        if v_table_count_p = 2 then
            delete dc_cashflow_delta;
        end if;
    end if;
```

end;

Comment: This should be a scheduled job, much easier

Comment: you can use DBMS_LOCK.Sleep( number of seconds)

Comment: I've updated the original question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664888/adding-exception-handling-and-improving-the-below-stored-procedure-and-job-in-or although I still think you should be able to schedule it.

Answer (score 1):

```
...
DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(60*35);
...
```